# Guaranteeing values in types in haskell

Tags: haskell, types

I have a data type called `Interaction` which is as follows:

```
data Interaction = Interaction AgentID AgentID Action Action
  deriving Show
```

I have a function which is designed to get the `Action` of the *other* agent (i.e. not "me") given an interaction:

```
getCounterAgentAction :: AgentID -> Interaction -> Maybe Action
getCounterAgentAction me (Interaction a b x y)
  | a == me   = Just y
  | b == me   = Just x
  | otherwise = Nothing
```

But I'd really like to get rid of the `Maybe` here and enforce that `Interaction` is an `Interaction` which contains the given `AgentID` (I guarantee this at runtime elsewhere in the codebase. Is there a way of doing this?

### Some more context (updated)

This code is part of an [evolutionary game-theory simulator](https://github.com/gfarrell/eye-for-an-eye). Each `Interaction` encodes how a pair of `Agent`s interacted in a given frame of the simulator (which is basically a time-slice or "round" of the game). In order to calculate the scores, I need to understand how the `Agent`s behaved, and so for each `Agent`, I check how they interacted with every other `Agent`. Therefore when I pass an `Interaction` to this scoring function, I'd like to be able to guarantee that the interactions I am passing have the `AgentID` I'm checking against in one of the fields. I already know they do at runtime because I'm filtering `[Interaction]` for those with that `AgentID` using this function:

```
findMyInteractions :: AgentID -> [Interaction] -> [Interaction]
findMyInteractions me = filter (\ (Interaction a b _ _) -> (a==me) || (b==me))
```

It seems to me, therefore, that my use of `Maybe` could be eliminated here if only I could somehow encode in the types that an `Interaction` is an `Interaction` of a given `AgentID`.

Comment: I wonder if GDP could help you https://ocharles.org.uk/posts/2019-08-09-who-authorized-these-ghosts.html . Can you post the complete set of type sgnatures for the API you have currently for context? Presumably you have many `AgentID` and `Interaction` pairs in your program? Maybe what you really want is `data Agent = Agent { otherAgent :: Agent, agentId :: AgentID ...` and a function that produces a pair of Agents which interact...

Comment: I'll take a look, thanks @jberryman. I'll update the post to include more context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that `Maybe Action` is the correct answer to the question "what is the action in the `Interaction` associated with the `AgentID` who isn't me?"  If you want the answer type to be `Action` you will have to ask a different question, or you will have to change the `Interaction` type.  The only way to ensure that the answer will be an `Action` is to guarantee that one of `a` and `b` won't equal `me`.  So lets create a type that can't express "a and b both of whom are me", that is, "me and b | a and me | two who aren't me":

```
data NotBothMe = MeAndA AgentID | MeAndB AgentID | NeitherAreMe AgentID AgentID
data Interaction = Interaction NotBothMe Action Action
getCounterAgentAction :: Interaction -> Action
getCounterAgentAction (Interaction (MeAndA a) x y) = y
getCounterAgentAction (Interaction (MeAndB b) x y) = x
getCounterAgentAction (Interaction (NeitherAreMe a b) x y) = x
```

Note that the `me` argument goes away, the me-ness is encoded in the NotBothMe value.  Furthermore, the ActionID fields of the NotBothMe type are not used either, we've obtained the information we need to implement `getCounterAgentAction` in building the `NotBothMe` value.

Here is a version with the unused `AgentID` fields removed:

```
data NotBothMe = MeAndA | MeAndB | NeitherAreMe
data Interaction = Interaction NotBothMe Action Action
getCounterAgentAction :: Interaction -> Action
getCounterAgentAction (Interaction MeAndA x y) = y
getCounterAgentAction (Interaction MeAndB x y) = x
getCounterAgentAction (Interaction NeitherAreMe x _) = x
```

Comment: Perhaps I'm not fully comprehending this, but the problem with applying this to my code is that the set of Interactions is going to be between all agents (AgentID is just an integer). I want to find out, for each Agent, what the counter-agent did in the last interaction, so `me` isn't fixed. I'm actually not trying to guarantee that not both are me, but rather than either 'a' or 'b' is the given id ('me'). I'm not sure if I can encode that constraint in Haskell's types (i.e. guarantee that the data type contains a particular value determined at runtime).

Comment: The condition that leads to a `Nothing` result in the original `getCounterAgentAction` is that neither `a` nor `b` equals `me`.  This suggests that you might partition the `Interaction` list based on whether the interaction involves `me`, with different types for those that do and those that don't:  `let (withme, withoutme) = partitionEithers (fmap (examineInteraction :: Interaction -> Either InteractionInvolvingMe InteractionNotInvolvingMe) interactions)`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I think I understand -- basically my filter function would output a list of `[InteractionInvolvingMe]` where `me` is a runtime determined value (of type `AgentID`). On that basis, I have a new type with which I can guarantee that `me` is contained in the `Interaction`, and therefore `getCounterAgentAction` would take that type, rather than `Interaction`, obviating the requirement for the `Maybe`. I'm going to test that out to see if it works, thanks.

Comment: Ok I think I've got it. Does this look right: https://gist.github.com/gfarrell/9f6c8e92610977be90a10f9ab301034e

Comment: Annoyingly I encountered a case which means I can't apply this specifically to my code, but I'll mark this as the right answer as it has solved the problem, thank you very much!